# Disabling auto-generated etags in NestJs app

Tags: express, nestjs

How can I disable auto-generated Etags in Nestjs?
It's based on Express, so there something like

```
expressApp.set('etag', false);
```

should do the trick.

How can I access express app from NestJs main?

Answer (score 9):

You can drop down to the express adapter using `getHttpAdapter()`, so you can do something like

```js
const bootstrap = async () => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().set('etag', false);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

[Docs on HttpAdapter here](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/http-adapter#outside-application-context-strategy)

Thanks rodorgas for the `.getInstance()` addition

Comment: It seems that on NestJS 8, we have to use `getInstance()` to reach the `set` method. So it becomes `app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().set('etag', false)`.